# using eclipse in linux(make instruction)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use Eclipse to use the make command. However, error orccured

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Is there a solution?

Thank you for reading my answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40586/using-eclipse-in-linux(make-instruction)/) by [An-Suyoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2900/an-suyoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Beside of the mentioned http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs page you need to know that at best you start Eclipse from terminal (e.g. bash) to provide the correct environmental variable settings.

Otherwise if you start the IDE from the GUI you need to setup the Paths either by hand or using the scripts

## make eclipse-project

and

## cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

respectively.

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you follow this page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs ?

Is your working directory in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2